# Draggable interactive graphic element using D3

Tags: d3.js, draggable

I have a challenging idea to build and couldn't think about a solution yet. The design request to have interactive/draggable graphics, as the one I send by the link below.

However, those graphics elements will be distributed in specific places on the page, with other elements around (Text, images, etc). The idea is to let the user "to play" with the graphics circles, just doing something 'cool and fun'. The user must be able to drag the circles from the graphics and change its visual all along the page.

The problem is: If I place this element in an specific place (inside a div, for example), if we drag the circles outside the 'canvas' area, the elements is no longer visible.

How could I place this canvas-div element in specific place and at the same time to allow the elements inside it to go the outside limited zone?

I thought about putting it in position relative or absolute with 100% height and width of the page, but it will be out of its place in responsive I guess, or pretty complicate to place always at a good place by just using % position. Any suggestion?

I'm using d3.js

Thanks!!

Heres the link: https://codepen.io/A8-XPs/pen/ePWRxZ?editors=0010

**HTML**

```
<svg width="500" height="350"></svg>
```

**JS**

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let points = d3.range(1, 10).map(function(i) {
    return [i * width / 10, 50 + Math.random() * (height - 100)];
});
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(0.5))

let drag = d3.drag()
        .on('start', dragstarted)
        .on('drag', dragged)
        .on('end', dragended);

svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'zoom')
    .attr('cursor', 'move')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')

 var focus = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(d3.extent(points, function(d) { return d[0]; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(points, function(d) { return d[1]; }));

focus.append("path")
    .datum(points)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", line);

focus.selectAll('circle')
    .data(points)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 5.0)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d[0]);  })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .style('cursor', 'pointer')
    .style('fill', 'steelblue');

focus.selectAll('circle')
        .call(drag);

focus.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);

focus.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
    .call(yAxis);

function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed('active', true);
}

function dragged(d) {
    d[0] = x.invert(d3.event.x);
    d[1] = y.invert(d3.event.y);
    d3.select(this)
        .attr('cx', x(d[0]))
        .attr('cy', y(d[1]))
    focus.select('path').attr('d', line);
}

function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed('active', false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PS: I got to solve the problem by just applying simple CSS to the SVG:

Overflow: visible;

Hopefully it will work in a real page scenario as well.

Comment: Issue: Once the circle is outside of the limited zone, it is no longer draggable